# Backup and Restore Ubuntu partitions (that exist on dual-boot system) to New Machine that is not dual-boot

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, partitioning, backup, boot-partition

Here is the scenario:

I have a dual-boot system that looks like the attached picture on gparted below. Anyways I would like to be able to take the partitions that Ubuntu needs and move them to another laptop that would be just for Ubuntu. I'm using CloneZilla for this. However, my concern is this:

Both Windows and Ubuntu need the 1st UEFI System Partition in the list that contains the MBR (revised with the installation of GRUB). So the question becomes do I also backup and restore the System Partition, along with the Root partition and Home partition? And if I do a move of all three of these partitions to the new machine, will the system be confused upon startup since the MBR partition table will no doubt reference the Windows partition as well?

Would it be better for me to simply install Ubuntu on the new machine so that it has its own System, Root, and Home partitions? And then on the old machine I would simply backup the Root and Home Partitions, which I would then use to overwrite the Root and Home partitions on the new machine?

I've scoured the Interwebs looking for a tutorial on how to do this, but no dice. Any direction would be much appreciated.

[partition table on dual-boot SSD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYwb9.png)

Comment: I always suggest new install in UEFI mode if UEFI system and gpt partitioning. Then you can do larger / (root) partition of 30GB or so & rest as /home or data partition(s). Then you restore from your normal backup your /home, your list of installed applications and if you installed any server type apps that have data in / folders. That also confirms your backup procedure is complete. With gpt partitioning, you only have a protective MBR, with one entry saying drive is gpt partitioned.

Comment: I just realized that the disk drive that I would be moving to has default MBR style partitioning. Would my overwrite of the root and home partitions even work if the restore is coming from a partition where the disk had a GPT style partition? @oldfred

Comment: Have to be careful. MBR & gpt are not compatible & you cannot just copy a partition with gpt. Gpt has GUID in partition, primary partition table & backup partition table. They must all match or you have major issues. May be possible to repair, but much better to partition with gpt, do new install, and copy data. Change new drive to gpt, either with gparted which will erase drive or with gdisk. Converting to or from GPT - must have good backups.
http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/mbr2gpt.html

Comment: Ok thanks @oldfred. So you would not recommend making a copy of your root directory, just your home? I would assume that replacing the root directory might mess up how the EFI System Partition would work. Unless there is a way to re-configure the System Partition after changing which partition is the active one?

Comment: It can be done, you have to reinstall grub to update it & edit fstab with new UUIDs. And some other settings. You need to be knowledgeable about internals of system. And those that are, find a new install quicker & easier. You should not use MBR with UEFI. Windows requires gpt, but Ubuntu will let you use MBR with UEFI boot, but really should not. I did a test install of Kubuntu to see if I liked it on my HDD. I did and had done some reconfiguration. Reinstalled on NVMe SSD in 10 minutes, copied /home which has no data in just a few minutes & linked data into /home. Less than an hour.