# Moving only half of a dual-boot setup

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2

So here is the problem I'm facing. I've been using a dual-boot setup (Windows 10/Ubuntu) for the past 4 years and I'm really happy with it and if Windows' disk management doesn't lie, then Windows and Ubuntu have two Partitions each.
I've also just bought a new Laptop with Windows 10 already installed on it and I would like to only move Ubuntu from the old setup to the new Laptop.
So what would be the best way to try and move only Ubuntu to the new Laptop (Fresh Windows + Loaded Ubuntu)? I **really** don't want have to reinstall everything.
Thanks :D

EDIT: Sorry if this has been asked before. I really couldn't find anyone with a similar problem as me.

Comment: Similar question. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1295753/backup-and-restore-ubuntu-partitions-that-exist-on-dual-boot-system-to-new-mac?noredirect=1#comment2201635_1295753 and my standard answer is a new install & restore from your normal backup. You always have good backups as drive can fail the day before you get new system. And it becomes a good way to know you have complete backups. Reinstall should not be difficult, restore /home as that is your settings & data and list of installed apps makes it easy to reinstall anything you added.

Comment: So would it be ok if I used the backup function of Ubuntu 20.0 to backup /home and / and then restored with the same tool on a new installation on the new Laptop ? Do I have to reinstall anything or will all the programs/packages be automatically installed ?

Comment: You can export list of installed apps & use that to reinstall them. The data for your apps will still be in /home. I prefer rsync, but many choices: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab & https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc (do not use dd or similar) If upgrading, you may want to edit it to remove obsolete, old kernels or others. It will not re-install anything already installed.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReinstallingSamePackages

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll be taking your advice.